# Is a comma needed before the name in a phrase like "In writing, Bob is struggling to form sentences"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

"In writing, Bob is struggling to form sentences."

Does the above sentence need the comma or some other form of punctuation?

Comment: Oh crikey, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence would be correct with or without the comma, though the comma helps make it clear that Bob himself is not being written.

Comment: Thank you very much!